# Im trying to make an obstical that goes left and right, yet it does nothing. Im using unity 5

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying to make an obstical that goes left and right, yet it does nothing. Im using unity 5, and here's my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DS : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public int s;
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        rb.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.left * s);
        rb.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.right * s);
    }
}
```

Comment: add "rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();" on start function

Comment: @MohamedAwad We can assume the rb is assigned in Inspector.

Answer (score 1):

You had:

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    rb.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.left * s);
    rb.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.right * s);
}
```

This means that every Update it pushes left and right at the same time.  The nett force is zero.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is making it so it moves left AND right at the same time to the same Rigidbody.

I am a bit confused as to your intention here as you can't move both left AND right at the same time.

If you want the object to move left when you press the left arrow key and right when you press the right arrow key, you should handle the key inputs so your code should look as follows:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DS : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public int s;
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
            rb.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.left * s);
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
            rb.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.right * s);
    }
}
```

Comment: I want it to move by itself with no user inputs.